# Horizontal Group Bar Chart - How to scale to 100% and how to specify the order of the layers

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I have the following code which produces:

[image]

The issue here is twofold:

1. The group bar chart automatically places the highest value on the top (i.e. for avenue 4 CTP is on top), whereas I would always want FTP to be shown first then CTP to be shown after (so always blue bar then red bar)
2. I need all of the values to scale to 100 or 100% for their respective group (so for CTP avenue 4 would have a huge bar graph but the other avenues should be extremely tiny)

I am new to 'R'/Stack overflow so sorry if anything is wrong/you need more but any help is greatly appreciated.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

# function to specify decimals
specify_decimal <- function(x, k) trimws(format(round(x, k), nsmall=k))

# sample data
avenues <- c("Avenue1", "Avenue2", "Avenue3", "Avenue4")
flytip_amount <- c(1000, 2000, 1500, 250)
collection_amount <- c(5, 15, 10, 2000)

# create data frame from the sample data
df <- data.frame(avenues, flytip_amount, collection_amount)

# got it working - now to test

df3 <- df

SumFA <- sum(df3$flytip_amount)
df3$FTP <- (df3$flytip_amount/SumFA)*100
df3$FTP <- specify_decimal(df3$FTP, 1)

SumCA <- sum(df3$collection_amount)
df3$CTP <- (df3$collection_amount/SumCA)*100
df3$CTP <- specify_decimal(df3$CTP, 1)

# Now we have percentages remove whole values 

df2 <- df3[,c(1,4,5)]

df2 <- df2 %>% pivot_longer(-avenues)

FTGraphPos <- df2$name

ggplot(df2, aes(x = avenues, fill = as.factor(name), y = value)) + 
  geom_col(position = "dodge", width = 0.75) + coord_flip() + 
  labs(title = "Flytipping & Collection %", x = "ward_name", y = "Percentageperward") + 
  geom_text(aes(x= avenues, label = value), vjust = -0.1, position = "identity", size = 5)
```

I have tried the above and I have looked at lots of tutorials but nothing is exactly precise to what I need of ensuring the group bar charts puts the layers in the same order despite amount and scaling to 100/100%

Comment: It's good that the data here is reproducible, but it's also a good idea, both for us and for your own debugging, to pare this down to just the part that's necessary for solving the problem. Just post the output of `dput(df2)`, since that's what you're plotting, and you can drop about 20 lines of code from the question

Comment: That being said, the issue of the order of colors is just that you need to set the factor levels to whatever order you want. There are lots of posts covering that. Not totally sure what you mean about scaling--if you're trying to show the share within a group, you might need to calculate that separately, and have that be the value you put on the y-axis

Comment: To add to @camille's note about using factors to order the bars, the issue with #1 is that your numeric values are set to character. If you set them to numeric, the order of the plot will be consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Camille notes, to handle ordering of the categories in a plot, you need to set them as factors, and then use functions from the forcats package to handle the order. Here I am using `fct_relevel()` (note that it will automatically convert character variables to factors).

Your numeric values are in fact set to character, so they need to be set to numeric for the chart to make sense.

To cover point #2, I'm using `group_by()` to calculate percentages within each name.

I have also fixed the labels so that they are properly dodged along with the bar chart. Also, note that you don't need to call ggplot2 or magrittr if you are calling tidyverse - those packages come along with it already.

```
df_plot <- df2 |> 
  mutate(name = fct_relevel(name, "CTP"),
         value = as.numeric(value)) |> 
  group_by(name) |> 
  mutate(perc = value / sum(value)) |> 
  ungroup()

ggplot(df_plot, aes(x = value, y = avenues, fill = name)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge", width = 0.75) +
  geom_text(aes(label = value), position = position_dodge(width = 0.75), size = 5) +
  labs(title = "Flytipping & Collection %", x = "Percentageperward", y = "ward_name") +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, this has resolved the issue. You make good comments regarding the code/simplyifing it down. The above worked perfectly.

Comment: In terms of scaling - as your graph showed above phil - the numbers now scale to 100 rather then randomly or to the exact amount of the bars. This is what I meant by scaling.

Comment: @LouisJohnston I mistakenly point to `value` instead of `perc` for the x axis, just change the name of the variable on your end.